# How to maintain app settings when user updates to new version

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

When we update an application, the settings which are selected by the user in the old version should be kept after updating to the newer version.

Let me explain this with an simple example:

Version 1.0 of my app has a switch that is ON by default but the user can set OFF. In the App Store I am going to publish next version— 1.1—with some modification but it also has the same switch. When the user updates it from the device the switch value should stay OFF.

How can I achieve this kindly reply me with your valuable comments...

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [NSUserDefaults](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/)

App 1.1 can easily read what App 1.0 wrote.

Answer (score 1):

When you update your app to a newer version, then the UserDefault have no change (If dont remove app). 
Then what we have to do is detect whether your app is updated to a newer version. What I did in my app is maintain a variable in UserDefault like "CurrentAppVersion", then when app is launched I check the currentVersion which getting from app Bundle, if they are difference and up, then I migrate my settings to a new version and update "CurrentAppVersion" to a new version also.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *currentAppVersion = [userDefault objectForKey:@"CurrentAppVersion"];

NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSLog(@"current version: %@, appversion: %@", currentAppVersion, appVersion);

if ([currentAppVersion isEqualToString:appVersion] == NO) {
    // Your app has just updated to new version, migrate your app settings.
} else {
    // NO, do nothings with your app settings.
}
```

Hope it help your much, :)

Answer (score 0):

The contents in Application Documents directory and Library directory will not change after app update. So what you should do is just write the settings (say a string "SWITCH:YES") to your Documents directory just like

```
[string  writeToFile:<#(NSString *)#> atomically:<#(BOOL)#> encoding:<#(NSStringEncoding)#> error:<#(NSError **)#>];
```

see this post [Retaining data after updating application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107148/retaining-data-after-updating-application)

Answer (score 0):

Your 1.1 version just needs to read the saved user settings written by the 1.0 version.   This is one reason that putting a versioning mechanism in your saved user data is a good idea, to make this type of upgrade simple.

Answer (score 0):

for sure you are saving your switch value some where on your first version so you can get it and apply it in the next version .. for me  when I make update to an app I usually build a backward computability class inside it I retrieve all the user settings and content and call it for the first time the app run and then I apply the old settings on the new version. Good luck